# Allow S3 event notifications to publish to SQS queue from any account in org

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

I tried this SQS queue policy:

```
{
      "Version" : "2012-10-17",
      "Statement" : [
        {
          "Effect" : "Allow",
          "Principal" : {
            "Service" : "s3.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Action" : "sqs:SendMessage",
          "Resource" : {sqs_queue_arn},
          "Condition" : {
            "StringEquals" : {
              "aws:PrincipalOrgID" : {our_org_id}
            },
            "ArnLike" : {
              "aws:SourceArn" : "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            }
          }
        }
```

When testing it, it DOES let you apply the policy to the queue without error, however it doesn't actually let S3 buckets send to it.

Currently I'm having to just add each account id individually which just doesn't scale for us.

Is there maybe an alternative way of doing this besides keeping track of all account ids manually?

Comment: Looking for a better doc but for now: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/kms-key-organization-account *"The aws:PrincipalOrgID global condition context key can't be used to restrict access to an AWS service principal. AWS services that invoke an API call are made from an internal AWS account that is not part of the AWS Organization."*

Comment: @luk2302 ahh this was super helpful. That makes sense. I found a way to do this using this info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found a way to do it:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "s3.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sqs:SendMessage",
      "Resource": {sqs_queue_arn},
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:ResourceOrgID": {our_org_id}
        },
        "ArnLike": {
          "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So like @luk2302 said in the comment, aws is the principal sending this and they don't have an org id. So we just look at the resource (s3 object) owner org id instead. This works.